# iOS Hiding Status bar and tab bar in iOS 6 + 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I've got a tabbed application and in one tab there is a UIWebView. When I rotate the device to landscape I'd like to make this UIWebView full screen over the status bar and tab bar.

//Edit

Ok, so now I've got it working in iOS 6 - originally when rotating and hiding the tab bar it would leave a black space where the tab bar was, so the fHeight code fixes this. However on iOS 6 it worked perfectly, but now it actually creates the black bar problem iOS 6 was having!! Any ideas for a workaround to this?

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
{
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [self hideTabBar:self.tabBarController];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:TRUE withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }
    else
    {
        [self showTabBar:self.tabBarController];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:FALSE withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }
}

- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    float fHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    if(  UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) )
    {
        fHeight = screenRect.size.width;
    }

    for(UIView *view in self.tabBarController.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, fHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, fHeight)];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    float fHeight = screenRect.size.height - 49.0;

    if(  UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) )
    {
        fHeight = screenRect.size.width - 49.0;
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, fHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, fHeight)];
        }
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

//Edit 2

I've tried using this but I'm not sure what view I need to pass in? It's supposed to work for iOS 6 and 7

```
- (void)setTabBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden view:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.tabBar.hidden == hidden)
        return;

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    float height = 0.0f;

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
    {
        height = screenRect.size.width;
    }
    else
    {
        height = screenRect.size.height;
    }

    if (!hidden)
    {
        height -= CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBar.frame);
    }

    void (^workerBlock)() = ^() {

        self.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.tabBar.frame), height, CGRectGetWidth(self.tabBar.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBar.frame));
        view.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(view.frame), CGRectGetMinY(view.frame), CGRectGetWidth(view.frame), height);
    };

    void (^completionBlock)(BOOL finished) = ^(BOOL finished) {
        self.tabBar.hidden = hidden;
    };

    if (animated)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:workerBlock completion:completionBlock];
    }
    else
    {
        workerBlock();
        completionBlock(YES);
    }
}
```

Comment: For your own well-being don't use `[UIView beginAnimations...]` and `[UIView commitAnimations]` anymore, but rather use the block-based animation methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the appropriate `UIViewController` rotation methods. Hiding the tab bar controller is easy enough, but the status bar is more difficult on iOS 7. Research how to do that and you should be fine.

Comment: In your update you're responding to the device orientation change notification. There's no need for that. You have a view controller which provides you with the exact methods. I would recommend running your code in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`

Comment: Ok I'll give it a go. Am I doing the right thing to hide the tab bar? It doesn't work.. and of course it doesn't hide status bar in iOS 7 - only iOS 6 and above

Comment: No, you're not - you never push a tab bar controller on to a navigation controller. Unfortunately hiding the tab bar is not easy. Maybe what you can do is push a new view controller on to your navigation controller on each orientation change. If it's landscape then it's a navigation controller with the property `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` set to `YES`, and on portrait the value is set to `NO`.

Comment: Or just try playing with the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property within that one view controller on the orientation changes callbacks.

Comment: It seems to hide the status bar in iOS 7 I need to call `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];` but this causes a crash in iOS 6

Comment: You can check if you can call that method using `respondsToSelector:`

Comment: Look up in the documentation the `UIViewController` method `prefersStatusBarHidden` and the Info.plist key `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`.

Comment: This is for the status bar not the tab bar however

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
    [super viewWillApper:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO];
    [super viewWillDisapper:animated];
}
```

Comment: That will just set it all the time.. not when it's in landscape orientation. Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

I got this working a while ago and forgot to post my answer as I had two similar questions going! Works in iOS 6 and 7

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

    BOOL toLandscape = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    void (^workerBlock)() = ^() {


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:toLandscape withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];

        float height = toLandscape ? screenRect.size.width : screenRect.size.height - CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame);

        float width = toLandscape ? screenRect.size.height : screenRect.size.width;

        webView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(webView.frame),
                               CGRectGetMinY(webView.frame),
                               width,
                               height);

        [self moveTabBarToPosition:height];
    };

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:workerBlock];
}
//Moving the tab bar and its subviews offscreen so that top is at position y
-(void)moveTabBarToPosition:(int)y {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.x, y, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height);

    for(UIView *view in self.tabBarController.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } else {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, y)];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }
}
```

In my case this is for my webview but theoretically you can give it any view. Works in iOS 6 and 7